# .htaccess redirect partial query string

Tags: redirect, query-string, partial

I'm trying to redirect the following kind of URL:

https://my_store/product_thumb.php?img=images/my_image_example.jpg&w=120&h=120
to:
https://my_store/images/my_image_example.jpg

I tried the following without success:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^product_thumb.php?img=images/(.*) images/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule product_thumb.php?img=images?(.*)$ images/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
`

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} $img=images [NC]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /images [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^img=images/(.*)&w=(.*)&h=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product_thumb.php$ images/%1? [L,R=301]